# How to render a Multilingual Quarto Website

Tags: r, web, multilingual, quarto, babelquarto

I have been effectively utilizing Babelquarto to render Quarto books in multiple languages. An example can be found [here](http://myaseen208.com/babelquarto2/). Additionally, I have been utilizing Quarto to create Quarto websites.

The R package Babelquarto is still experimental and only contains four functions: `quarto_multilingual_book`, `register_further_languages`, `register_main_language`, and `render_book`. I am intrigued to know if it is possible to employ a similar approach to generate multilingual Quarto Websites.

I reported the same on Babelquarto GitHub pages [here](https://github.com/ropensci-review-tools/babelquarto/issues/4#issuecomment-1596638748).

Comment: Please try to refrain from adding tags in posts every time you mention a technology - they aren't very useful in this context, and it makes eye-scanning a question harder than it needs to be.